# Iterate over 2 arrays in bash - only looping over first value in each array

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

So i am trying to loop over two array's in bash but im struggling to get this to work, it seems to stop on the first iteration and doesn't loop the entire array, please note i am using IFS as i want to define the separator.

```
#!/bin/bash

protocol="udp,tcp-client,udp,"
port="1111,2222,3333,"

# split comma separated string into list from VPN_REMOTE_PROTCOL variable
IFS=',' read -a vpn_remote_protocol <<< "${protocol}"

# split comma separated string into list from VPN_REMOTE_PORT variable
IFS=',' read -a vpn_remote_port <<< "${port}"

for index in "${!vpn_remote[*]}"; do

        echo "iptables -A OUTPUT -o docker_int -p ${vpn_remote_protocol[$index]} --dport ${vpn_remote_port[$index]} -j ACCEPT"

done
```

output is:-

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o docker_int -p udp --dport 1111 -j ACCEPT
```

i want the output to be:-

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o docker_int -p udp --dport 1111 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o docker_int -p tcp-client --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o docker_int -p udp --dport 3333 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *most immediate* problem in the original code was use of `vpn_remote` as the name of the array for which we're searching for keys, instead of `vpn_remote_protocol` or `vpn_remote_port`. The *next* problem is use of `"${!array[*]}"`, which generates a *single string concatenating all the keys together*; just as `for item in "two words"` only runs *once*, with `two words` as the value assigned to item, looping over `"${!vpn_remote_port[*]}"` here would be running `for index in...` *only once*, with `"0 1 2"` as the item. (By contrast, with the incorrect variable name, `""` is what `"${!array[@]}"` evaluates to; in a numeric context that's treated as `0`, which is why you see the first item and no others).

---

#### Moral Of This Story

Use `"${!array[@]}"`, never `"${!array[*]}"`, `${!array[*]}` or `${!array[@]}` without understanding the differences and having an explicit reason.

Thus:

```
#!/bin/bash

protocol="udp,tcp-client,udp,"
port="1111,2222,3333,"

IFS=',' read -a vpn_remote_protocol <<< "${protocol}"
IFS=',' read -a vpn_remote_port <<< "${port}"

for index in "${!vpn_remote_port[@]}"; do
    echo "iptables -A OUTPUT -o docker_int -p ${vpn_remote_protocol[$index]} --dport ${vpn_remote_port[$index]} -j ACCEPT"
done
```

...which, when [run in an online interpreter](https://ideone.com/C7G7kD), emits as output:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o docker_int -p udp --dport 1111 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o docker_int -p tcp-client --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o docker_int -p udp --dport 3333 -j ACCEPT
```

---

#### Going Deeper: Why The Other Alternatives Are Each Wrong

Why `"${!array[@]}"`? Let's compare behavior of each, but in a more challenging case when our keys aren't purely numeric (though we *could* generate bugs by using the incorrect approaches even with purely-numeric keys, if we had numbers in our `IFS` value):

```
declare -A array=(
  ["first key"]="first value"
  ["second key"]="second value"
  ["third key"]="third value"
)

printf '%s\n' 'Using "${!array[@]}":'
printf ' - %s\n' "${!array[@]}"

printf '\n%s\n' 'Using "${!array[*]}":'
printf ' - %s\n' "${!array[*]}"

printf '\n%s\n' 'Using ${!array[*]}:'
printf ' - %s\n' ${!array[*]}

printf '\n%s\n' 'Using ${!array[@]}:'
printf ' - %s\n' ${!array[@]}
```

...for which we [see the following output](https://ideone.com/zjY18d):

```
Using "${!array[@]}":
 - second key
 - third key
 - first key

Using "${!array[*]}":
 - second key third key first key

Using ${!array[*]}:
 - second
 - key
 - third
 - key
 - first
 - key

Using ${!array[@]}:
 - second
 - key
 - third
 - key
 - first
 - key
```

So:

- `"${!arrayname[*]}"` is wrong because it expands to a single string with all the keys concatenated (with the first character in `IFS` -- a space by default -- between them).
- `${!arrayname[*]}` and `${!arrayname[@]}` are both wrong because the keys are subject to word-splitting and glob expansion before they can be treated as a list of items
- `"${!arrayname[@]}"` does the Right Thing, treating each key as a single word, not subject to operations that could mangle it first.

Comment: Array names are: vpn_remote_protocol and vpn_remote_port, not vpn_remote.

Comment: @chepner, see edit showing a distinction in practice.

Comment: @chepner, insofar as the question is using the wrong array name, that just makes it off-topic here as caused by a typo. Overlooking that error allows the question to be treated as on-topic.

Comment: @chepner with quotes this `${!vpn_remote_port[*]}` will end with syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown of this, tbh i didnt fully understand the significance of `[*]` or `[@]` at all, thus the confusion, i was under the completely misguided notion that `[*]` was some sort of wildcard to combine both arrays, thus the array name of `vpn_remote[*]`

Comment: Ahh -- sounds like you were confusing it with a _different_ construct, `"${!vpn_remote@}"`, which will expand to the names of the variables that start with `vpn_remote`. Once you have the `[@]` or `[*]` instead of just `@` or `*`, though, it's looking at keys within a single array, instead of referring to multiple variables that start with a prefix.

Comment: Why not declaring arrays straight from start rather than reading? https://ideone.com/MImBsp

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over `${!vpn_remote_port[*]}` or `${!vpn_remote_protocol[*]}`(without ")

But what exactly is happening here? Why only looping over first value in each array? The main reason is wrong array name so index var is empty and it's only one loop. Because you are looping over this `""` empty string. And if we try to fetch data from `${vpn_remote_port[$index]}` with empty `$index` it'll return first value(index 0).

Comment: Good practice is to switch to `[@]` and keep the quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, also incorporated the [@] as suggested in the above comment.

Comment: BTW, one can get bugs with unquoted `${!vpn_remote_port[*]}` even with a non-associative array, so long as one has a sufficiently weird IFS value. See https://ideone.com/w9tEPO demonstrating such a bug.